# AngularJS 1.2: Is it possible to use ngAnimate inside a nested repeater?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-animate

In AngularJS 1.2+, with ngAnimate, it is very easy to display a list of item one by one with animation.

However, I have some trouble apply the same method to a nested array.

Let's say I have a 3x3 2d array:

```
$scope.matrix = [
    [{a: 1,b: 2}, {a: 1,b: 2}, {a: 1,b: 2}],
    [{a: 1,b: 2}, {a: 1,b: 2}, {a: 1,b: 2}],
    [{a: 1,b: 2}, {a: 1,b: 2}, {a: 1,b: 2}]
];
```

and html to display this 2d array with nested `ng-repeat`:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="row in matrix ">
    <ul>
      <li  class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="entry in row track by $index">{{entry.a}}/{{entry.b}}</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and finally the `ngAnimate` css to **fade-in each entry one by one** every second:

```
.animate-repeat.ng-enter-stagger {
    transition-delay: 1000ms;
    transition-duration: 0s;
}
.animate-repeat.ng-enter {
    transition: 1000ms ease-in all;
    opacity: 0;
}
.animate-repeat .ng-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

This, does not work as I tested out: http://plnkr.co/edit/BaPTL33b2y1ITIb7uZuy?p=preview

I assume current version of AngularJS will not auto-add ngAnimate classes for the inner repeater, is this correct?

And if so, is there a workaround/solution to problem, so I can display each item in a 2d array one by one with animation? (prefer not flatten the 2d array.)

Thanks.

Comment: In the end, I just flattened the array (using 1d array simulate 2d array).

Comment: So did you have to change your HTML? I can't figure out how you flattened the array and kept the same HTML.

Comment: @WilliamNeely Hi, sorry for this super late response. Yes I flatted the html as well. Then I used absolute position for all child elements, so they can be positioned in X,Y space.